# Run a script on shutdown and not on reboot

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown

I'm executing a script on `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` when the server is stopping
But I would like to execute it only on `shutdown` behavior, not whendoing a `reboot`.

I tried to get the value with `$1`but for `reboot` or `shutdown`, but it always sending a `stop` message

The script I'm currently running:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          shutdown
# Required-Start:    
# Required-Stop:     sendsigs
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: shutdown
# Description: 
### END INIT INFO

shutdown_script.sh

exit 0
```

And run by
`sudo update-rc.d shutdown_job start 19 0 6 .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the script in different runlevels.

```
/etc/rc0.d - While system shuts down.

/etc/rcS.d - While system boots

/etc/rc1.d - Working as singel user (user specific on login)

/etc/rc2.d - Working as multiple users

/etc/rc3.d bis /etc/rc5.d - not used in ubuntu

/etc/rc6.d - While system restarts
```

Comment: How to distinguish between shutdown and shutdown + reboot?

Comment: `shutdown -h` will be runlevel 0. `shutdown -r` will be runlevel 6. There's no "shutdown + reboot"; a shutdown ends with the system halted, a restart results in the system rebooting.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explication! It works perfectly only in rc0.d

`sudo update-rc.d -f shutdown_job remove`
`sudo update-rc.d shutdown_job start 19 0 .`